# cross domain sso within Websphere App server and Jboss

Tags: single-sign-on

I want to create a POC which demonstrate the SSO between two different application hosted on the different server and different machine(1.e. **App-1** :- Websphere App server 7.0.0.15 and **App2** :-Jboss 6.2 EAP).

Both the application share the same LDAP (user repository) so user can navigate from One Application to Another application (App-1 to App-2 or vice versa).

Please suggest me which SSO technique would be feasible in such setup.

Answer (score 0):

If they apps are not deployed in the same cookie domain (check https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265) or deployed in a public suffix (https://publicsuffix.org/) you can not use an SSO mechanism based on cookies unless the 'product' offers a way to perform CDSSO (like OpenAM). Then you may need to use 'SAML2' or 'OAuth2/OIDC'.